# MATLAB:How to write in the empty rows in Excel

Tags: excel, matlab, export-to-excel

I have two arrays in MATLAB and i want to import them to excel

```
A=[1,2,3,6,7,9]
B=[5,6,7,8,9,0]
```

Im using this command to write in excel

```
xlswrite('name',A,'','A1:F1')
```

I want to write the first Array (A) in row 1 in excel, I would like to write Array B in the next empty row.
Sometimes i have alot of arrays that i need to export to excel
and it dosent make any sense to use `xlswrite` and to change the range every single time i execute the code!

Any ideas?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your MATLAB version is older than R2019a, use:

```
>> xlswrite('name',[a;b],'','A1:F2')
```

Otherwise, use the recommended [writematrix](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/writematrix.html):

```
>> writematrix([a;b],'name.xls')
```

Comment: Why didn't you say that in your question then?

Comment: How can we know that if you don't tell us?

Comment: Your original question has been answered. If you have a question about Simulink usage, open a different one